# Is my local area network accesible to others when sharing my Internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, connection, sharing

Sometimes I share my Internet connection with my neighbours via the Network Manager GUI (Ubuntu 12.04) but there is something I am worried about...

Is it sharing just the Internet connection or is my home local network (with all my PCs, shared folders, smartphones, network printers and other devices) somehow exposed too?

My local network has a 192.168.1.x range while the shared connection is in the range 10.x.x.x but, what happens if my neighbour changes his ip to one in my range? Is there a bridge? or is he going to be alone in that range because I'm just sharing the Internet and nothing more?

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on many things.

Best way is to try it out by yourself, as there is not much point in theory when it's easier to try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it out like 10robinho suggested.

Well, my local area network is unreachable from the shared connection network, so it seems pretty safe. I can't see any device of my local network from the shared connection network even using the same ip range.